# Como extrair dados específicos de um arquivo html com php?

Tags: php, html

Gostaria de saber como eu posso extrair parte do conteúdo de um arquivo `HTML`. Este arquivo tem dezenas de e-mails e nomes e gostaria de extrair estes dados. Alguém pode me ajudar a fazer isto?

```
<div class="tcell tquick">
  <div style="background-color: #ddd; padding: 4px;"> 
      <span> <b class="the_nome">Marcos Vinícius Nascimento Pereira;</b> </span> 
  </div>
  <br>
  <div> </div>
  <div>
    <div class="c the_email">mvnpereira@gmail.com</div>
  </div>
  <div> </div>
</div>
```

Neste caso eu gostaria de extrair o `nome` e o `email` com o **PHP**.

Comment: Todo em email fica dentro de um div com a classe `c the_email`?

Comment: Sim, eu vou gerar essas classes dentro do **email** e do **nome** conforme foi demonstrado no exemplo !!! Obrigado.

Comment: Se você vai criar o *HTML* e depois vai extrair dados, não seria mais simples criar no formato que você quer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

É justo para esse tipo de tarefa que PHP possui suporte a [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/).
Suponhamos que você tem sua saída HTML dessa forma e que ela sob um URL como localhost/emails.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div class="tcell tquick">
        <div style="background-color: #ddd; padding: 4px;">
            <span> <b class="the_nome">Ciclano;</b> </span>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div> </div>
        <div>
            <div class="c the_email">ciclano@gmail.com</div>
        </div>
        <div> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tcell tquick">
        <div style="background-color: #ddd; padding: 4px;">
            <span> <b class="the_nome">Fulano;</b> </span>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div> </div>
        <div>
            <div class="c the_email">fulano@gmail.com</div>
        </div>
        <div> </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Então você poderia carregar esse conteúdo em string com [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) e usar outra classe chamada [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php):

```
<?php 

$html_content = file_get_contents('http://localhost/emails.html');

$dom = @DOMDocument::loadHTML($html_content);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//div[@class="tcell tquick"]');    

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $nome  = $xpath->query('div/span/b[@class="the_nome"]', $node)->item(0);
    $email = $xpath->query('div/div[@class="c the_email"]', $node)->item(0);

    echo $nome->nodeValue  . PHP_EOL;
    echo $email->nodeValue . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Isso fará exatamente o que você precisa.

Comment: Através da resposta fiz adaptação no meu código que retornou o que eu precisava. Perfeito e obrigado !!!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer usando expressões regulares. Fiz um exemplo parecido, precisava pegar o preço do soja no site do canal rural.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]