# Como pegar texto de uma outra página e inserir em um input?

Tags: php

Estou com uma dúvida pequena em um projeto que estou desenvolvendo.

Acontece o seguinte:

> Tenho este input em uma página **(index.php)**:

```
<input id="exibe" value="Aqui vai ficar o texto **que foi** copiado">
```

> Na outra página, tenho este elemento **(puxa.php)**:

```
<font id="pegar" class="campo">Aqui fica o texto **que vai ser** copiado</font>
```

> O que preciso é que quando a pessoa acessar o **index.php** que possui o **`input`** com **`id="exibe"`**, esse **`input`** terá seu **`value=""`** **preenchido com o texto que se encontra na outra página** (**puxa.php**) que está dentro o **`<font>`** com **`id="pegar"`**.

É possível fazer isto?

Comment: Será o texto que está dentro do `<font>`, no caso "Aqui fica o texto **que vai ser** copiado" :)

Comment: Ele já está gerado. É uma página já feita. O que quero é tirar esta dúvida que há anos venho tentando descobrir. Kkkkkkkkk :)

Comment: Sua dúvida é como pegar o texto do HTML?

Comment: Simmm :D Exatamentee!!!

Comment: Já tem respondido no site então: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/78621/70

Comment: Mas ele tem que ser colocado no value="" do input.

Comment: Ele puxa um texto que está em outra página, e joga esse texto dentro do value do `input`, na página principal.

Comment: Exato, pergunta com vários assuntos diferentes acaba ficando ampla demais. E ambas ja tem resposta no site, só dar uma pesquisadinha. De qualquer forma, a parte complicada é o que eu indiquei no link acima. o resto é só um `echo` no `value`, que resolve (não se esqueca de escapar os caracteres especiais).

Comment: Algo tão simples? Olha só o tamanho da pergunta!

Comment: Muito obrigado @Bacco era isso mesmo que eu queria!!! Acabei de fazer funcionar aqui :)

Comment: só não se esqueça do htmlentities() no echo do value, senão pode ter problemas com caracteres especiais.

Answer (score 1):

Alexandre, a forma mais simples de fazer é da seguinte forma:

index.php:

```
<html>
<body>  
    <form id="form1" method="post" action="puxa.php" >
        <input id="pegar" name="pegar" class="campo" value="Aqui fica o texto **que vai ser** copiado"/>
        <input type="submit" value="enviar" />
    </form>     
</body>
```

puxa.php:

```
<html>
<body>  
    <input id="exibe" value="<?=$_POST['pegar']; ?>">  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Amigo, tem certeza que testou esse código? Kkkkkk

Comment: tenho certeza. Algum problema em compilar? Talvez seu php nao esteja configurado corretamente. Qual erro encontrou?

Answer (score -1):

Sim. envie o valor da página através de uma requisição ajax ou faça um post.
Você pode salvar esse valor em um objeto do tipo Session. Em php seria: $Session['nome_session'] = 'valor enviado';

na outra pagina seria necessário apenas chamar o valor: 
echo $Session['nome_session'];

Comment: Você poderia editar sua resposta? Ficou muito confusa, rsrs